# How to disable 'Select Audio Device' popup when plugging in a device

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, devices, notify-osd

I have been on Ubuntu 22.04 for a while now but suddenly I got a OSD popup that gives me an option to select audio input device every time I plug in a audio device.

I've seen ways to disable thins with extensions etc, but I want to know id there is a way to disable this from the default GNOME settings or something.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you've found an answer but I have and thought I should reply for anyone else in search of an answer. This is not a fix per se but what I would consider a workaround. Until GNOME figures out a more elegant method of handling this it will have to do.

I have a laptop that doesn't have a combo jack so it can never be anything but headphones that I'm plugging in. The best option I have yet found is an extension named "Auto select headset".

From the author:

> A simple gnome-shell extensions that bypasses the headset selection dialog and signals that a headset is plugged in.

I have only just started using it but it seems to do the trick.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3928/auto-select-headset/

https://github.com/josephlbarnett/autoselectheadset-gnome-shell-extension